# Can I set up a Jenkins job build number automatically?

Tags: svn, jenkins, build-process, jenkins-plugins

I'm aware of this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin but it requires a manual step. How can I setup a jenkins build number automatically inside a Jenkins job's configuration page for example? Essentially, I want to use an SVN revision number as the BUILD_NUMBER for a job. I know how to extract the SVN revision number, but I want to know how to use it for my purpose.

Comment: The build number should not be used like SVN revision number because you might run multiple builds on the same revision. I do not believe Jenkins supports overwriting a build result because doing so would also require Jenkins somehow supporting simultaneous builds that all occur on potentially the same build number.

Comment: @hofan41 says "...because you might run multiple builds on the same revision" - This does NOT apply to us.

Comment: What if your job configuration was incorrect (such as a script error) or jenkins itself experienced an error (such as a network disconnect) and you need to rerun it?

Comment: Do you **really** want to change the build number itself, or just the name that is displayed for each build? The first is not possible, for the second, there is a plugin: [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin).